# Incomplete response received from application in nodejs selector server

Tags: node.js, directadmin, nodejs-server

so as the title mention my app works on google cloud, heroku, and ovh..
but i can't get it to work on

> directadmin nodejs selector

static pages are served but can't login due to "Incomplete response received from application"

Comment: Did you find any solution since?

Comment: No i stopped playing around with it cause server crashes everytime.. but i think you need to put your node server (api) in node selector and the static files somewhere else.. not sure though..